# Using jQuery and JSON to display groups from MeetUp API

Tags: jquery, json, api, meetup

I am trying to make a widget that will display Meetup groups someone belongs to based on their Member ID.

This is my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Meetup Groups by Member ID</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?&sign=true&member_id=8377069&page=20&api&key=API_KEY&only=name,link", displayGroups);

function displayGroups(data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        htmlString += '<h3><a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">' + item.name + '</a></h3>';
    });
    $('#groups').html(htmlString);
}
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="groups"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the JSON output (when I just put the request URL in the browser):

```
{"results":[{"name":"The New York Python Meetup Group","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/nycpython\/"},{"name":"WordPress NYC Meetup Group","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/WordPressNYC\/"},{"name":"Coworking Community NYC","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/coworking-nyc\/"},{"name":"NYC Ruby Roundtable","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/nycruby\/"},{"name":"Why Leave Astoria?!","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/whyleaveastoria\/"},{"name":"#betaNYC, formerly Open NY Forum","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/betanyc\/"},{"name":"New York Open Statistical Programming Meetup","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/nyhackr\/"},{"name":"Django-NYC","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/django-nyc\/"},{"name":"NYC Redditors","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/NYC-Redditors\/"},{"name":"Startup Addicts NYC","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/startupddict\/"},{"name":"Woodside - Sunnyside Runners","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Woodside-Sunnyside-Runners\/"},{"name":"NY HTML5 User Group","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/NY-HTML5-User-Group\/"},{"name":"Hacks\/Hackers New York","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/hackshackersny\/"},{"name":"New York City Geek Adventure Group","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Astoria-Long-Island-City-Geek-Adventure-Group\/"},{"name":"Mukti's Kitchen","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/MuktisKitchen\/"},{"name":"Unearth Ruby","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/unearthruby\/"},{"name":"Awesome People of Sunnyside Queens Unite!","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Awesome-People-of-Sunnyside-Queens-Unite\/"},{"name":"New York Data Visualization and Infographics","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/New-York-Datavisualization-and-Infographics\/"},{"name":"Google NYC Tech Talks","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/google-nyc-tech-talks\/"},{"name":"Crisismappers NYC","link":"http:\/\/www.meetup.com\/Crisismappers-NYC\/"}],"meta":{"lon":"","count":20,"signed_url":"http:\/\/api.meetup.com\/2\/groups?radius=25.0&order=id&desc=false&member_id=8377069&offset=0&format=json&only=name%2Clink&page=20&fields=&sig_id=8377069&sig=651d9c728df7bb62915fdc1fbae1b2b87d36c35b","link":"https:\/\/api.meetup.com\/2\/groups","next":"https:\/\/api.meetup.com\/2\/groups?key=4d366a414432e7e442d6eb1e124f&radius=25.0&order=id&member_id=8377069&format=json&page=20&desc=false&offset=1&only=name%2Clink&fields=&sign=true","total_count":26,"url":"https:\/\/api.meetup.com\/2\/groups?key=4d366a414432e7e442d6eb1e124f&radius=25.0&order=id&member_id=8377069&format=json&page=20&desc=false&offset=0&only=name%2Clink&fields=&sign=true","id":"","title":"Meetup Groups v2","updated":1366809331000,"description":"\"\"","method":"Groups","lat":""}}
```

I am not getting any errors in the console. Nothing gets printed to the page. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I think somehow I'm not actually retrieving any data. Console shows no response when I test the HTML page, but shows a response when I just run the API call URL in the browser.

Comment: You should iterate over `data.results`, not over `data.items`.

Comment: should all references to items/item be results/result?

Comment: `$.each(data.items, ...` should be `$.each(data.results`, the rest should stay unchanged.

Comment: OK, tried that, no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Herp Derp. needed **`?callback?`** in the API request URL.

Full Answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meetup Groups by Member ID</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?callback=?&sign=true&member_id=8377069&page=20&api&key=API_KEY&only=name,link", 
function (data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data.results, function (i, item) {
        htmlString += '<h3><a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">' + item.name + '</a></h3>';
    });
    $('#groups').html(htmlString);});
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="groups"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do think the function needs to be defined before used as callback. I would change this to:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.meetup.com/2/groups?&sign=true&member_id=8377069&page=20&api&key=API_KEY&only=name,link", 
function (data) {
    var htmlString = "";
    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
        htmlString += '<h3><a href="' + item.link + '" target="_blank">' + item.name + '</a></h3>';
    });
    $('#groups').html(htmlString);});
```

This avoids the unnecessary functure definition and makes your code cleaner.